# How to link ejs file to a js file in node.js app

Tags: ejs

I'm using ejs templates for the first time. I have a basic index.ejs file, where I want to link to a js file (map.js).

In index.ejs, I've done:
 `<script type='text/javascript' src='./map.js'></script>`

In map.js, I've simply put:
 `document.onload(function(){
  alert("ready!");
})`

However, I don't see the alert come through when I go to my index page. The file structure is like this:

-map.js
-views
---index.ejs

Where map.js and the views folder are on the same level, and index.ejs is within the views folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an issue that the file cannot be found or that Jquery is not defined? check your console to see if/what error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the script tag?

I see

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./map.js'>
```

but it have to be like :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../map.js'>
```